# Bug in meta badges

Tags: bug

When I visit my profile in this meta site, the badge area notifies me that I should take the tour to earn my first badge (as normal on all SE sites). However, taking the tour neither grants the badge nor removes the notice.

Pressing the "See New Questions" button at the end of the tour takes me to the main site, not the Meta site.

This seems to be some sort of bug specific to this Beta site or to Beta sites in general.

Comment: Dupe on uber meta: [The new profile shouldn't mistakenly imply that you can earn the Informed badge on a meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258179/241919) (since 2015)

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes. Still a bug. However, I did not see that in EESE, which suggests to me that it’s only in beta sites.